# android manifest is not recognized in activity

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I define a custom permission inside manifest and then try to use that inside activity for handling broadcast with permission between two apps. When I type, studio show me manifest part of package. No error symbol. But when I build, I get error.
Activity code below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.send);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("com.payment");
                intent.setPackage("com.example.receivebr");
                sendBroadcast(intent, Manifest.permission.payment);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

permission in manifest.

```
<permission android:name="com.test.payment"/>
```

I am getting error:

> D:\android\test\send\app\src\main\java\com\example\sendbr\MainActivity.java:26:
> error: package Manifest does not exist
> sendBroadcast(intent, Manifest.permission.payment);

Error image is below.
[image]

Can someone suggest what could be the problem. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the package:

`import android.Manifest;`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @ShawnHemelstrand The first line of my answer IS the explanation, I believe this is enough for a simple answer.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to gradle version. Studio will show import suggestion.
But issue will remain same once you build or run.
**manifest inclusion is working up to gradle-4.9 version.**

**It will not work if you have higher version.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> error: package Manifest does not exist

It seems that you have import the wrong package for `Manifest`. Anyway, I'm not sure your custom permission is correct. For example, according to [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/defining), the `protectionLevel` field is required...

Comment: I have checked and there is no import statement. I while typing, i see that studio is showing correct package in hint. Can you suggest if these is any other issue and Also I don't have permission to open the link. Can you please provide the permission.